# Only show wanted artifacts in 'Produced the following x artifact(s)'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a case where my tests produce a lot of logfiles from the Jenkins build but since those logfiles are shown in a .html report it would be nice to hide those so instead of having 50 artifacts shown only the .html are there.
Is there a plugin available to do this?

I only want to hide them in the 'artifacts in 'Produced the following x artifact(s)' section so the "build artifacts" and workspace still have the artifacts available.